# Bounding upper tail of Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, upper-lower-bounds, gaussian-integral

In some example, I saw the following bound:
$$\int_1^\infty e^{-2t s^2} ds \leq e^{-2t}\sqrt{\pi/(2t)}.$$

I would like to prove this for my own understanding but ran into some trouble obtaining the factor $e^{-2t}$. What I know how to show is that
\begin{align*}
\int_1^\infty e^{-2ts^2}ds & \leq \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-2t s^2} ds\\
& = \sqrt{2\pi/(4t)},\\
& = \sqrt{\pi/(2t)},
\end{align*}
using facts about the normalization constant of a Gaussian PDF. But it is not immediate to me how to get the, presumably better, bound including $e^{-2t}$. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try the substitution $s= \sqrt{1+u^2}$ and make use of the bound $\frac{ds}{du} \leq 1$

Comment: +1 Ah I see how this works--amazing! Just out of curiosity, was this something you've seen before or was there something that led you to suggest this substitution? I might have eventually tried this but I could've been stuck for days...

Comment: Had to discover it from scratch today.